# set only X axis in new Point (X,Y) in C#?

Tags: c#, picturebox, point

I'm new to C# and I cant find an answer to this anywhere. So, help would be greatly appreciated.
How do I set a pictureBox's X axis but leave its Y the same. I have tried a few differnt things, but is there a way to use new Point(X, Y) without changing the Y?

```
this.MyPictureBox.Location = new Point(244, Y);
```

Comment: "but leave its Y the same" --- the same to what? Just specify `this.MyPictureBox.Location.Y` explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the 'Left' property instead of the 'Location' property.

Answer (score 2):

`this.MyPictureBox.Location = new Point(244, this.MyPictureBox.Location.Y);`